# How can I invoke a virtual method handle using ByteBuddy's InvokeDynamic class?

Tags: byte-buddy

I've found the [`InvokeDynamic` class](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/implementation/InvokeDynamic.html) and have made it work with a `static` method handle acquired via `MethodHandles.Lookup.findStatic()`.

Now I am trying to do the same thing, but with a virtual method handle acquired via `MethodHandles.Lookup.findVirtual()`.

I can cause my bootstrap method to run, and I make sure in my bootstrap method that I'm returning a `ConstantCallSite(mh)`, where `mh` is the result of calling `MethodHandles.Lookup.findVirtual()`.  (This part all works fine, i.e. I understand how "indy" works.)

However, when I use the resulting `Implementation` as the argument to an `intercept()` call, I cannot pass the actual object on which the method represented by the method handle is to be invoked.  This is due to the `withArgument()` method being used for two contradictory purposes.

Here is my recipe:

```
Implementation impl =
  InvokeDynamic.bootstrap(myBootstrapDescription, someOtherConstantArgumentsHere)
  .invoke(theMethodName, theMethodReturnType)
  // 0 is the object on which I want to invoke my virtual-method-represented-by-a-method-handle;
  // 1 is the sole argument that the method actually takes.
  .withArgument(0, 1);
```

There are some problems here.

Specifically, it seems that `withArgument()` is used by ByteBuddy for two things, not just one:

1. Specifying the parameter types that will be used to build a `MethodType` that will be supplied to the bootstrap method.  Let's say my virtual method takes one argument.
2. Specifying how the instrumented method's arguments are passed to the actual method handle execution.

If I have supplied only one argument, the receiver type is left unbound and execution of the resulting `MethodHandle` cannot happen, because I haven't passed an argument that will be used for the receiver type "slot".  If I accordingly supply two arguments to (1) above (as I do in my recipe), then the method handle is not found by my bootstrap method, because the supplied `MethodType` indicates that the method I am searching for requires two arguments, and my actual method that I'm finding only takes one.

Finally, I can work around this (and validate my hypothesis) by doing some fairly ugly stuff in my bootstrap method:

1. First, I deliberately continue to pass two arguments, not one, even though my method only takes two arguments: `withArgument(0, 1)`
2. In my bootstrap method, I now know that the `MethodType` it will receive will be "incorrect" (it will have two parameter types, not one, where the first parameter type will represent the receiver type).  I drop the first parameter using `MethodType#dropParameterTypes(int, int)`.
3. I call `findVirtual()` with the new `MethodType`.  It returns a `MethodType` with two parameter types: the receiver type that it adds automatically, and the existing non-dropped parameter type.

(More simply I can just pass a `MethodType` as a constant to my bootstrap method via, for example, `JavaConstant.MethodType.of(myMethodDescription)` or built however I like, and ignore the one that ByteBuddy synthesizes.  It would still be nice if there were instead a way to control the `MethodType` that ByteBuddy supplies (is obligated to supply) to the bootstrap method.)

When I do things like this in my bootstrap method, my recipe works.  I'd prefer not to tailor my bootstrap method to ByteBudddy, but will here if I have to.

Is it a bug that ByteBuddy does not seem to allow `InvokeDynamic` to specify the ingredients for a `MethodType` directly, without also specifying the receiver?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Would you want to try a pull request or create a reproduction? I will certainly look into it.

Comment: I will hopefully get to this soon (now that I have the workaround I'm working on downstream stuff ).  It should be relatively easy to see.

Answer (score 2):

What you described, is entirely independent of Byte-Buddy. It’s just the way how `invokedynamic` works.

[JVMS, §5.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.6)

> #### 5.4.3.6. Dynamically-Computed Constant and Call Site Resolution
>
> To resolve an unresolved symbolic reference `R` to a dynamically-computed constant or call site, there are three tasks. First, `R` is examined to determine which code will serve as its *bootstrap method*, and which arguments will be passed to that code. Second, the arguments are packaged into an array and the bootstrap method is invoked. Third, the result of the bootstrap method is validated, and used as the result of resolution.
>
> …
>
> The second task, to invoke the bootstrap method handle, involves the following steps:
>
> 1. An array is allocated with component type Object and length *n*+3, where *n* is the number of static arguments given by `R` (*n* ≥ 0).
>
>    The zeroth component of the array is set to a `reference` to an instance of `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup` for the class in which `R` occurs, produced as if by invocation of the `lookup` method of `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles`.
>
>    The first component of the array is set to a `reference` to an instance of `String` that denotes `N`, the unqualified name given by `R`.
>
>    The second component of the array is set to the `reference` to an instance of `Class` or `java.lang.invoke.MethodType` that was obtained earlier for the field descriptor or method descriptor given by `R`.
>
>    Subsequent components of the array are set to the `reference`s that were obtained earlier from resolving `R`'s static arguments, if any. The `reference`s appear in the array in the same order as the corresponding static arguments are given by `R`.
>
>    *A Java Virtual Machine implementation may be able to skip allocation of the array and, without any change in observable behavior, pass the arguments directly to the bootstrap method.*

So the first three arguments to the bootstrap method are provided by the JVM according to the rules cited above. Only the other arguments are under the full control of the programmer.

The method type provided as 3rd argument always matches the type of the `invokedynamic` instruction describing the element types to pop from the stack and the type to push afterwards, if not `void`. Since this happens automatically, there’s not even a possibility to create contradicting, invalid bytecode in that regard; there is just a single method type stored in the class file.

If you want to bind the `invokedynamic` instruction to an `invokevirtual` operation using a receiver from the operand stack, you have exactly the choices already mentioned in your question. You may derive the method from other bootstrap arguments or drop the first parameter type of the instruction’s type. You can also use that first parameter type to determine the target of the method lookup. There’s nothing ugly in this approach; it’s the purpose of bootstrap methods to perform adaptations.